# spring-RabbitMQ manually listen to queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm new in rabbitmq.I'm using spring-amqp to implement the feature.
As we know spring provide @RabbitListener to register a listener to queue when the app initialization. 
I want to design a function when I click some button, a new consumer will be created and listen to a specified queue.
Java base provide channel.basicConsume() method to consume a queue.
Is spring provide such function ?

I want to implement like :

producer keep sending messages to a fanout exchange.
when a consume wants to join, call function1 -> create queue and binding to exchange -> consume messages.
when a consume wants leave, call function2 -> disconnect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Use one of the `RabbitTemplate.receive()` or `convertAndReceive()` methods to get messages one-at-a-time, you can set a `receiveTimeout` in case there are no messages.
2. `RabbitTemplate.execute()` with a callback that gets a channel that you can call `basicConsume()` on. This is a lower-level option and won't do any conversion for you.
3. Create a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (or `DirectMessageListenerContainer`) dynamically and start/stop it as needed.
4. ...

In all cases, you can use a `RabbitAdmin` to create/bind the queue, for all except option 1, it would probably an auto-delete queue that will be removed when the consumer is cancelled. With option 1, you would have to use a non-auto-delete queue and remove it with the `RabbitAdmin`.

I would suggest that #3 is the most efficient using pure Spring AMQP.

You could also use Spring Integration with an inbound channel adapter and a publish-subscribe channel; that way you only need one queue (per application instance) and then subscribe a new `MessageHandler` to the channel for each user.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use Spring Integration, however.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was considered using Option 1, but the performance looks not good. I will take a look at the option 3 which you recommend.